# Golang slice append and reallocation

Tags: go, slice, goroutine

I've been learning go recently and had a question about the behavior of slices when reallocation occurs. Assume I have a slice of pointers to a struct, such as:

```
var a []*A
```

If I were to pass this slice to another function, and my understanding is that internally this passes a slice header by value, that runs on a separate goroutine and just reads from the slice, while the function that launched the goroutine continues to append to the slice, is that a problem? For example:

```
package main

type A struct {
    foo int
}

func main() {
  a := make([]*A, 0, 100)
  ch := make(chan int)
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    a = append(a, &A{i})
  }
  go read_slice(a, ch)
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    a = append(a, &A{i+100})
  }
  <-ch
}

func read_slice(a []*A, ch chan int) {
   for i := range a {
     fmt.Printf("%d   ", a[i].foo)
   }
   ch <- 1
}
```

So from my understanding, as the read_slice() function is running on its own goroutine with a copy of the slice header, it has an underlying pointer to the current backing array and the size at the time it was called through which I can access the foo's.

However, when the other goroutine is appending to the slice it will trigger a reallocation when the capacity is exceeded. Does the go runtime not deallocate the memory to the old backing array being used in read_slice() since there is a reference to it in that function?

I tried running this with "go run -race slice.go" but that didn't report anything, but I feel like I might be doing something wrong here? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC does not collect the backing array until there are no references to the backing array. There are no races in the program.

Consider the scenario with no goroutines:

```
  a := make([]*A, 0, 100)
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    a = append(a, &A{i})
  }
  b := a
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    b = append(b, &A{i+100})
  }
```

The slice `a` will continue to reference the backing array with the first 100 pointers when append to `b` allocates a new backing array. The slice `a` is not left with a dangling reference to a backing array.

Now add the goroutine to the scenario:

```
  a := make([]*A, 0, 100)
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    a = append(a, &A{i})
  }
  b := a
  go read_slice(a, ch)
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    b = append(b, &A{i+100})
  }
```

The goroutine can happily use slice `a`. There's no dangling reference.

Now consider the program in the question. It's functionaly identical to the last snippet here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!